# Installing droidcam error ppa not found

Tags: apt, droidcam

I'm following [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/install-droidcam-wireless-android.html) guideline on setting up droidcam so I can use my android phone as a webcam, the first two scripts run okay but when I run `sudo apt-get update` there's an error related to the installation

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/droidcam/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: PPA not working, but deb yes: 

64 bits
https://www.dev47apps.com/files/600/droidcam-64bit.tar.bz2

32 bits
https://www.dev47apps.com/files/600/droidcam-32bit.tar.bz2  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKn6YY0pSEM

Answer (score 0):

This software is kind of old, and may not work on newer Ubuntu installations.

Open `Software & Updates`, Additional Software tab. Find the repository definition that contains `paolorotolo` and change the OS version from xenial to vivid. Reload the software database when exiting. You should be able to install droidcam now.